# How to make a program run a second time?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //I used 'print' instead of 'println' just to make it look a little cleaner in the console.
        System.out.print("Input your first number: ");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num1 = sc1.nextInt();

        //I use doubles for my variables just in case the user wants to divide.

        System.out.print("Input your second number: ");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num2 = sc2.nextInt();

        /* I used words rather than the actual symbols for my operators just to get practice using scanners for strings.
         * Until now I'd solely been using them for int variables. And also due to the small detail that before programming,
         * I had no idea what a modulo was and I felt that would be confusing to a random person.
         */

        System.out.println("What would you like to do with these numbers?(Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, or Check Divisibility): ");
        System.out.println("Simply type 'check' to check the divisibility of your two numbers.");
        Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str1 = sc3.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        /* toUpperCase to prevent the user from creating an error by typing their in put in a 'unique' way.
         *It took me several failures to finally look up toUpperCase. 
          */

        double num3;

        switch(str1) {
        case "ADD":
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("The sum is: " + num3);
        break;
        case "SUBTRACT":
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("The difference is: " + num3);
        break;
        case "MULTIPLY":
            num3 = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("The product is: " + num3);
        break;
        case "DIVIDE": 
            num3 = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println("The quotient is: " + num3);
        break;
        case "CHECK":
            num3 = num1 % num2;
            System.out.println("The remainder is: " + num3);
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please ensure that two numbers were entered and that you entered a valid math operation.");
        break;
        }//switch statement

    }//main method

}//class
```

How would I get my code to run again if I wanted to maybe add another number to my answer? I'm just trying to get some practice in with my Java (I'm extremely green) and I apologize in advance if my question is too broad.

Comment: Use a `while` or `for` loop.

Comment: Encase it in a `while` loop, and add a exit option for the user from the `Scanner` that will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following small program

```
boolean quit = false;
while(!quit) {
    System.out.print("Enter Something:");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc1.nextLine();
    if(input.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") == 0) {
        quit = true;
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println("You entered " + input);
}
```

In this sample we keep asking them to enter something and print it out unless that input is "quit" in that case we use the `continue` statement to skip the rest of the loop and go back to the top of the while loop and re-evaluate the condition for another iteration. If you entered 'quit' this will evaluate to false and stop the loop and exit the program.

Heres a sample input/output from the program. Notice there is no "You entered quit", this is because the `continue` statement brought us back to the top of the while loop.

```
Enter Something:hello
You entered hello
Enter Something:quit
```

---

Now how can you adapt this to your program? Heres a small sample of how you can do one of your inputs

```
double num1 = 0;
String input1 = sc1.nextLine();
if(input1.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") == 0) {
    // quit was entered, leave the loop
    quit = true;
    continue;
}
try {
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(input1);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // user entered something that isnt a number, quit the program for now
    // you can change this to whatever behavior you like in the future
    quit = true;
    continue;
}
```

This will likely leave you with some validation questions like "I want to have my user try again if they input an invalid number" Those are all possible using this method and it leads you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, `main()` is a callable method. Instead of using a `while` or `for` loop, you could just call it again at the end of the main method method.

```
// Put this at the end of your main method
System.out.print("Do you want to execute again? (yes/no)");
boolean repeat = sc1.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals("YES");
if (repeat) {
    main(null); // You're not using any arguments in main()
}
```

On a separate note, you don't need all three of `sc1`, `sc2`, and `sc3`. They're basically the same. You could probably use `sc1` everywhere and remove `sc2` and `sc3` completely.

Comment: Thank you for catching that! I kind of breezed through making it and forgot to check for unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

// something like this then ask if to do another run if not set flag false

boolean flag = true;

```
while(flag)
{


System.out.print("Input your first number: ");
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
double num1 = sc1.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put all your logic around a *while* loop which will grant to you to repeat your task until a condition is reached. 
Maybe you can ask to the user to insert the string "EXIT" when he wants to exit from your program.

In your case I'll do something like this:

```
boolean exitFlag = false; 

do {
    // <put your logic here> 

    String answer = sc3.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    if (answer.equals("EXIT")) {
        exitFlag = true;
    }


} while(!exitFlag);
```